# Google AdMob is not working in Xamarin Form iOS for larger screen devices like iPhone 7 and 7 Plus

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, admob

I am working on an iOS app using Xamarin Forms platform. I am using Google AdMob and implemented it following this URL http://motzcod.es/post/154696375922/xamarinforms-google-admob-ads-in-ios

It works perfectly fine on every device and simulator with iOS version as 10.2

It also works with iOS version 10.3 but only on fewer devices like iPhone 5s and 5c but not on devices and simulators for iPhone 6, 6s, 6s Plus, 7, 7 Plus

Debugging it further throws following error, "Error Domain=com.google.ads Code=13 "Request Error: Received invalid response." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Request Error: Received invalid response., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Request Error: Received invalid response.}"

I searched for this error and applied a fix too but that did not work as well.

I appreciate if someone could please help. Thanks

Comment: I could be mistaken but I believe theres now a requirement in the later iOS versions for URL's to be 'https' rather than 'http'

Comment: Hi There, in order for this to run a key NSAppTransportSecurity must be added which I already did the first time I run the project.

Comment: Is there someone who can help on this? I am running on the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [App Transport Security](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/app-transport-security) and add the following lines to the `Info.plist`.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key><dict> 
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key> 
<true/></dict>
```

This may resolve your problem.

Comment: Hi There, thanks for your reply. I already added these keys the first time I run project.

Answer (score 0):

just FYI I followed this blog http://motzcod.es/post/154696375922/xamarinforms-google-admob-ads-in-ios

BannerView is used in the custom renderer of iOS like this

```
        adView = new BannerView(size: AdSizeCons.SmartBannerPortrait,
                                       origin: new CGPoint(0, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Height - AdSizeCons.Banner.Size.Height))
        {
            AdUnitID = bannerId,
            RootViewController = GetVisibleViewController()
        };
```

Instead of creating its object using parameterized constructor, just create it like this

```
        adView = new BannerView()
        {
            AdUnitID = bannerId,
            RootViewController = GetVisibleViewController()
        };
```

Above implementation fixed the issue in all the iOS Versions and Devices.